# Define global variable inside a function

Tags: javascript, global-variables

Like python is it possible to define global variable inside a function ?

for eg -

in python

```
def testFunc():
    global testVar
    testVar += 1
```

is there a way to define testvar global in javascript inside a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply ignore the `var` keyword.

```
function testFunc() {
    testVar = 1;       // `testVar` is a Global variable now
}
```

**Note:** In the Python version of your code, you are not *defining* a global variable. You are referring the variable `testVar` defined in the global scope.

Quoting from [`var` MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Description),

> assigning a value to an undeclared variable implicitly declares it as a global variable (it is now a property of the global object)

Answer (score 1):

You can assign it to the window-object:

```
function test() {
    window.globalvariable = 'something';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply declare it outside of the function:

```
var testvar;

function test() {
    testvar = 1;
    //the rest of the code
}
```